# Suggestions for reaction conditions to prepare methyl 2,4,6-trimethylbenzenesulfonate

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

I'm a beginner in organic chemistry and I wish to produce methyl 2,4,6-trimethylbenzenesulfonate.

My reactants are 2,4,6-trimethylbenzenesulfonyl chloride (solid crystals) and methanol (solvent as well as reactant). The product of this reaction should be methyl 2,4,6-trimethylbenzenesulfonate and HCl.

Now I've tried these many conditions: distilling the methanol, nitrogen inert atmosphere, slight heating about 40 °C, room temperature, closed system.

After trying these conditions and their combinations I'm not getting the product in the desired amount.

Kindly help me out and suggest a few tweaks and optimizations if possible. As far as my knowledge goes the problem seems to be with methoxy group.

This is the entire synthesis process, please check it out. I am stuck on step two of this synthesis.

[image: Entire synthesis]

Comment: Can you add structures or link to structures? Maybe I'm missing something, but the names of these compounds don't make sense. Trimethyltoluene sulfonate would be a tetramethylbenzene sulfonate, of which there are a couple isomers.

Comment: I guess, you want to prepare **methyl 2,4,6-trimethylbenzene-1-sulfonate** from **2,4,6-trimethylbenzene-1-sulfonyl chloride**. Could you please check and edit your question?

Comment: @jerepierre and others, guys sorry for the delay. I have added the structures and the synthesis process please have a look.

Comment: @AVyas I've changed the name of the compound to methyl 2,4,6-trimethylbenzenesulfonate, which is the product of reaction 1. I am still confused though because your edit says that you are having problems with step 2, which is the transfer of the methyl to a pyridine. Could you clarify which step you are having problems with and what exactly the problem is? "Not getting the product in the desired amount" could be anything.

Comment: I'm closing this as unclear because I cannot tell which step there is a problem in and what the problem actually is, cf @jerepierre's comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Are you following a literature procedure? It looks like you should be able to find a reliable method that you can reproduce. Some general hints for optimisation:

- Use a base to mop up the $\ce{HCl}$ that is produced. Either an
  organic base like pyridine (preferably) or triethylamine or you can use an
  inorganic base like $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{Na2CO3}$ under 
  [Shotten-Bauman conditions](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/schotten-baumann-reaction.shtm)  i.e. as a biphasic aqueous-organic system
- Increase the reactivity of the nucleophile. Methoxide is a much better nucleophile. You can use commercially available $\ce{MeONa}$ or you can create it by something like $\mathrm{^tBuOK/MeOH}$

EDIT: I am assuming OP tries to make **methyl** 2,4,6-trimethyl toluenesulfonate since he states that MeOH is a reagent.